# how can I test my facebook page tab app from localhost

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a facebook page tab app. When I set page tab URL in app settings to something like `localhost/fbapp`, it doesn't work since the page tab is not simply iframe. Is there any workaround to resolve this?

**EDIT**

I'm building facebook ***page tab*** with ASP.NET MVC-3.0 with fb C# SDK.

What I've tried so far is to modify `hosts` file to point the URL I have on app settings to localhost(127.0.0.1). I've been testing facebook app in this way always but it doesn't work in facebook page tab.

Comment: No workaround. For pagetabs (authenticated & non-authenticated), FB will post a signed_request to the site whenever pagetab is loaded. You can try simulating this by recording this signed_request and use it for your localhost's HTTP_POST. Note: Signed_request has an expiry!

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured, and I am testing in that way. I actually wanted to test parsing signed_request. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my answer below on quickly parsing signed_request

Comment: Use a domain on your public IP for test, you can setup DNS TTL for 1 minute if your IP changes.

Comment: @EricYin Thanks for a comment, unfortunately I'm within f/w that I have no control..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue with facebook page tab. It seems that they don't accept `http` on page tab even I have sandbox mode enabled. All I have to do is set up IIS to work with `https` and run the app over the ssl. It is now working perfectly. Thank you guys for all help

Comment: You might have "secure browsing" enabled in your Facebook Security settings. https pages/apps will only load https urls inside the canvas.

Comment: @AshwiniDhekane you are right. I have that enabled and everything needed to be served via https.

Answer (score 3):

In Application setting in page tab url set

```
http://localhost/yourpagetabdir/
```

[image: setting on facebook]

I am using this setting for my page application test frmlocalhost its works fine from my ASP.Net Development server if you are using IIS server make sure your IIS server allow page in iframe.

after this if u want to get page-signed request

```
 Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection s = new FacebookConfigurationSection();
                s.AppId = "AppID";
                s.AppSecret = "Secret";
                FacebookWebContext wc = new FacebookWebContext(s);
                dynamic da = wc.SignedRequest.Data;
                dynamic page = da.page;
                string curpageid = page.id;
                bool isLiked = page.liked;
                bool isAdmin = page.admin;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I know I can test facebook app in this way, but page tab doesn't seem to be just an iframe.

Comment: You're asking FB to post to itself with that config.

Comment: That’s just not true. The POST request happens __client side__, in your browser – and your own browser on your own machine knows pretty well, that localhost is to mean that very machine he’s running on.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/MyFanPageAPP-Community/248834891855992?sk=app_348300468514893 check this page tab i am currently use this page tab application for testing from my localhost

Comment: Yes, actually localhost does work. it's just SSL setting like I said in my answer and @AshwiniDhekane mentioned. I have secure browsing enabled on my account and every facebook page was under https, thus my facebook page needed to be served by https. there is no difference b/w facebook app and page tab. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your hosts file so that when you go to `http://example.com` it links to your `http://localhost/yourapp`

Here's how to do it:

- **Windows**: http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp (your localhost URL should have a valid website format: 127.0.0.1 dummydomainname.tld)
- **MacOS**: http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-setup-virtual-hosts-mamp-environment/ (again, make sure you have a valid website format)
- **Linux**: You probably know how to do this already :)

This should work as then the iframe would point to a valid URL, which on your local machine would point to your content. Note that this won't work if you access the tab from other computers since for them the URL would point to something else (or nothing, depending on what domain name you choose).

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this before and it's still not working. I know this works in fb app page but app tab on fb page.

Answer (score 0):

Using FB PHP SDK for example, you can post the signed_request and parse it with a few lines:-

```
require_once ("facebook.php"); // this file comes from the SDK
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'get_appID_from_app_menu';
$config['secret'] = 'get_secret_below_appID';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
print_r($signed_request);
```

Avoid that lenghty example given in FB's blog. Good luck coding :)

Comment: thanks but I'm doing with C# SDK. and I know how to do this. Just wanted to test it in my local via page tab.